# Java 8 / Lambda: multiple collect/Collectors.groupingBy with sorting

Tags: java, java-8

Im having the following code

```
    Map<BigDecimal, Map<Optional<BigDecimal>, List<TestDto>>> test =  data.getTestDtos().stream()
    .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(TestDto::getValue1,
            Collectors.groupingBy(dto -> Optional.ofNullable(dto.getValue2()))));
```

Is there any chance to sort at least the outer/first map by its keys (BigDecimal)?

My goal is to order both maps by its keys (BigDecimal and Optional BigDecimal) but im not sure how to do this with lambda...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `mapSupplier` you can use a `SortedMap` like `TreeMap`.

```
SortedMap<BigDecimal, Map<Optional<BigDecimal>, List<TestDto>>> test =  data.getTestDtos()
  .stream()
  .collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(TestDto::getValue1, TreeMap::new,
      Collectors.groupingBy(dto -> Optional.ofNullable(dto.getValue2()))));
```

---

To sort the inner `Map` you have to write your own `Optional-Comparator` and the solution should look like this:

```
SortedMap<BigDecimal, SortedMap<Optional<BigDecimal>, List<TestDto>>> test =  data
  .getTestDtos()
  .stream()
  .collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(TestDto::getValue1, TreeMap::new,
      Collectors.groupingBy(dto -> Optional.ofNullable(dto.getValue2()),
        () -> new TreeMap<>((o1, o2) -> {
          if (o1.isPresent() && o2.isPresent()) {
            return o1.get().compareTo(o2.get());
          } else if (o1.isPresent()) {
            return -1;
          } else if (o2.isPresent()) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        }),
        Collectors.toList())
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a `TreeMap` from your `HashMap` and it will be sorted

```
  Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly solution is

```
Map<BigDecimal, Map<Optional<BigDecimal>, List<String>>> sorted = test.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
                .peek(entry -> entry.setValue(new TreeMap<>(entry.getValue())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```